# How to customize the color of an HTML output file generated from Git Bash?

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows, vimdiff, bash, git

I have used the following command in Git Bash to perform a 'vimdiff' for 2 XML files.

```
vimdiff  xml1.xml xml2.xml -c TOhtml -c 'w! result.html' -c 'qa!'
```

The HTML file which is getting generated is too flashy. The differences are highlighted in Magenta and the background is Black in color. Also the font colors are Cyan and Green. Is there a way to modify the color settings, so that the result file doesn't contain too many bright colors?

Below are the things which I have tried out, but it doesn't give the required result.

1. Tried changing the 'Foreground' and 'Background' color in the Bash terminal and then performed the vimdiff operation. But the HTML file still contains bright colors.
2. In Vim I checked for [`:h :colorscheme`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3acolorscheme), [`:h :TOhtml`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3aTOhtml), [`:h :highlight`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3ahighlight) but not sure what exactly should be changed.
3. I found that most of the sites mention about changing the .vimrc file. I was able to locate the `.vimrc` file but not sure what changes should be made to the file.

Is there any resolution for the problem?

HTML output:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried editing the HTML to your liking after generation?

Comment: @chicks: Thanks for the response. I can edit the HTML post creation, but I want the entire process to be automated. Hence was looking for solution where in the file will get generated as required. I was able to modify the vimrc file and the required results are being displayed now :-)

Comment: If you can edit it once to be how you like then it should be straight forward to write a script to do this post-processing step for you.   I'm glad you already found a method that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [2HTML section of help](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#2html.vim) says:

> After you save the resulting file, you can view it with any browser.
>   The colors should be exactly the same as you see them in Vim.

So change the color scheme to something you like by calling `:colo` in your command before `TOhtml`. Using scheme *molokai*, for example, you have this:

```
vimdiff  xml1.xml xml2.xml -c 'colo molokai' -c TOhtml -c 'w! result.html' -c 'qa!'
```

I've verified that this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to find another way also for getting the desired result. I was able to modify the vimrc file and now the HTML file which is getting generated is in much better reading form :-) Thanks a lot for the response !

Comment: @AnitaPradhan No problem. Are you just calling `:colo` in your vimrc or something else/more?

Comment: In vimrc file I added the following lines at the end of the file:   
      highlight! link DiffText ToDo
      highlight DiffAdd cterm=bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=Red gui=bold guifg=White guibg=Red
      highlight DiffDelete cterm=bold ctermfg=7 ctermbg=1 gui=none guifg=White guibg=Red
      highlight DiffChange cterm=bold ctermfg=Black ctermbg=White gui=none guifg=Red guibg=White
      highlight DiffText cterm=bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=Red gui=none guifg=bg guibg=Red

Comment: After making changes to vimrc, I executed this line:  vimdiff  xml1.xml xml2.xml -c TOhtml -c 'w! result.html' -c 'qa!'; and the HTML file was in a much readable format.

Comment: You've almost created a new color scheme except not quite...this could be pretty brittle and/or will probably have negative side effects eventually. You should just put it in a `myscheme.vim` (for example; choose any name you want)  in `.vim/colors`. You can use an existing scheme from `$VIMRUNTIME/colors` as a guide. Then put `colo myscheme.vim` in your vimrc file.

Comment: Alternatively, find an existing color scheme that you like online and drop the file in the colors folder. There are literally hundreds of freely available schemes out there. https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes and http://vimcolors.com/ are a couple places you can look.